# Issue with Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT imps.Interest_name as PopularInterests,
       imps.SUM(Count) AS Total_Count,
       ints.Vertical_Name 
FROM Impressions imps
  INNER JOIN Interests ints ON imps.Interest_name = ints.Interest_name
GROUP BY imps.Interest_name
HAVING imps.SUM(Count) > 10000;
```

The query gives me the error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Cannot find either column
>   "imps" or the user-defined function or aggregate "imps.SUM", or the
>   name is ambiguous

My tables are as follows:

Impressions:

```
Interest_Name   Count
 Geo_934293      1107
 Geo_934293      852
 Geo_934293      934
 Geo_8133957     1810
 Geo_8133957     909
 Geo_8133957     463
 Geo_8133957     736
 Geo_8133957     7000
```

Verticals:

```
Interest_Name   Vertical_Name
 Geo_934293         X
 Geo_8133957        Y
```

And the expected result would be:

```
Popular_Interest  Total_Count   Vertical_Name
   Geo_8133957      10918             Y
```

Not sure where I am going wrong? I assume it has to do with the `SUM` function.

Comment: _imps.SUM(Count) > 10000_  What is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUM(imps.Count)` instead of `imps.SUM(Count)` (it is invalid syntax):

```
SELECT  
    imps.Interest_name as PopularInterests, 
    SUM(imps.Count) AS Total_Count, 
    ints.Vertical_Name 
FROM Impressions imps
    INNER JOIN Interests ints ON imps.Interest_name = ints.Interest_name
GROUP BY imps.Interest_name, ints.Vertical_Name 
HAVING SUM(imps.Count) > 10000;
```

Comment: Thank you for the Syntax help. In the group by clasue I probably need to add ints.Vertical_Name as well. Without which i get an error.

Comment: @TauseefHussain You are absolutely right, in `GROUP BY` you need to add all columns that are not used in aggregate functions. I updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: @TauseefHussain can you see my comment 30 mins ago what i said SUM(Imps.count)

Comment: @mohan111 Yes I did acknowledge it!